# htaccess 301 redirect does not work

Tags: asp.net, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect this link

- localhost/Scripts/prodlist.asp?strSearch=REMS+POWER+PRESS+E+ATTREZZATURE&strSearchType=OR&strSearchMin=0&strSearchMax=0&strSearchCat=0&curPage=86&sortField=sku

to

- localhost

So far I tried different things but none work. Right now I am here:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(strSearch=TRE+ESSE+TRE+IDROSELF+BIDET+WC+SOSPESO+IDEAL+STANDARD+SERIE+21+STEP+SANITARI+CERAMICA+PIATTO+DOCCIA+EDRAULICA)$
RewriteRule ^Scripts/prodlist\.asp$ localhost [R=301,L]
```

But I still get the 404 error.Can anyone help me solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not match the query string you try to capture in your `.htaccess` snippet. Also, you try to externally redirect to `localhost`, which would be resolved to `http://example.com/localhost`.

The best I could come up with to match your original link, is the following

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^strSearch=(.+)&strSearchType=(.+)&strSearchMin=(.+)&strSearchMax=(.+)&strSearchCat=(.+)&curPage=(.+)&sortField=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^Scripts/prodlist\.asp$ http://example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

However, instead of using the general capture patterns, you could just specify the complete query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^strSearch=REMS+POWER+PRESS+E+ATTREZZATURE&strSearchType=OR&strSearchMin=0&strSearchMax=0&strSearchCat=0&curPage=86&sortField=sku$
RewriteRule ^Scripts/prodlist\.asp$ http://example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried using the complete query but it doesn't work. Also i replaced the site with localhost, the actual link is something like http:// www.example.com/Scripts/prodlist.asp?strSearch=REMS+POWER+PRESS+E+ATTREZZATURE&strSearchType=OR&strSearchMin=0&strSearchMax=0&strSearchCat=0&curPage=86&sortField=sku

Comment: It works for me with this configuration: https://github.com/janpapenbrock/stackoverflow-36102680/blob/master/public/.htaccess